# check if a taxnomy queried in $wp_query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, advanced-taxonomy-queries

Is there a way to check if there is any taxonomy that has been queried in the global $wp_query?

Comment: I am using `$wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy']`, is it a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$wp_query->query_vars['taxonomy']` alone won't do it, but yes, you can check the object itself.

However, something like [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax) may be more appropriate. A lot depends on context and you query is all but lacking in that.

Comment: if i have a url like this `http://mysite.com/?post=post-1&tax1=term1&tax2=term2`, will is_tax() return `TRUE`??

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. Have you tried it?

Comment: seems like yes is_tax() returns true.

I will use is_tax then! thx